# Reading bytes from the empty space on a disk

Tags: c, macos, disk, low-level, computer-forensics

It's widely known that in general, when you delete a file on disk on most (all?) modern OSes, the bytes of that file aren't removed, but the space is 'freed' and not overwritten with other data until it's used for another write operation.

I'm also aware that on UNIX-like systems, I can read the bytes on disk directly from its representation in the filesystem at `/dev/whatever`.

However, `/dev/whatever` returns all the bytes of everything on the disk, including files that still 'exist' in the user-facing sense, and what I'd really like to do is identify and read *only* the bytes on disk that remain after the deletion of some resource - so the data that still exists in the 'free' space of the disk (I'm aware that file recovery and digital forensics tools exist which can recover these files, but for my purposes I need to do something slightly-closer-to-the-metal - I'm interested in getting a bytestream of the data remaining on the empty space of the disk, with no additional structure).

Therefore, is there any way I could access (for instance) the allocated and unallocated ranges of disk space programaticaly, then read the bytes corresponding to the unallocated ranges from disk? I'm pretty agnostic when it comes to programming language - I'm assuming this is going to involve low-level APIs callable from a little C programme, or something similar.

I'm assuming this is OS / Filesystem dependent - I'm on Mac OS X and APFS if this helps, but would appreciate tips for any combination of OS/FS as i'm eventually going to port this project to other platforms.

Any tips or insight much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's a generic way. What you need to do is (1) find where the files are, then (2) read everything else. Note that a less-than-half-full disk is mostly empty space anyway, so I'm not sure how much benefit you get by avoiding the files.

Comment: Aha thanks, that sounds sensible! Avoiding the files is (annoyingly) a fairly specific constraint in the final thing - i'm interested specifically in 'empty space' (it's more or less an art project rather than something concretely practical). However, I could start by reading the entire disk as a proof of concept then look into identifying the empty space later, if that's gonna prove to be the tricky part!

Comment: partclone.*fstype* with the -D option can create a "domain log" that shows which parts of the block device are used. The block device probably needs to be unmounted first. It doesn't currently support APFS though.

Comment: ooooh thank you Ian, that's super useful! I'm sure i can track down a non-APFS disk to experiment with :-). Great stuff!

Comment: Linux/ext?fs has debugfs command with dump_unused function, which does exactly that. At least for the `ext` filesystem family. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/e2fsprogs/+/master/debugfs/unused.c

Comment: The acrual question is: given a random disk block (number), is this block in use? Does the FS *think* it is in use? And this question can only be answered by the particular FS logic.

Comment: I think there's also some way to query where a file is located on the disk, so you could go through all the files, and ask where each one is located.

Comment: @wildplasser well, that's the same thing as asking whether it's actually in use

Comment: @wildplasser: Finding unused blocks is an incomplete solution. One must also find unused bytes in blocks containing fragments.

Comment: With some exceptions. (think: fsck) @EricPostpischil : Yes, you are right. Forgot about that...

Comment: Filesystems usually keep their free and occupied blocks in some kind of data structure, which varies from filesystem type to filesystem type. You need to know what this data structure is for any given filesystem type. For example for the ext4 file system your program needs to be able to find all the free block bitmaps as described [here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout).